# Change the output of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I read a CSV file with `pandas.read_csv("sample.csv", sep=";")` and got this output:

[image: output]

However I want to get my dataframe output like this:

[image: expected]

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the difference here?

Comment: Describe your environment, your problem and some sample code, if you want accurate answers. You have not formulated any question, only shown a table visually presented in two different ways. I suggest you read further on how to present a pandas dataframe in different ways for your specific working environment, as I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ['tabulate'](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) library. Maybe not exactly the same layout you show, but might help.

Comment: Could you explain how to use _tabulate_ to solve the problem. Read [answer].